# Fillter grep results by range and display in column

Tags: awk, sed, grep, uniq

I have extract this data with `grep` from my log stats, data and value:

```
Apr-1 -4
Apr-1 -2
Apr-1 -5
Apr-1 5
Apr-1 95
Apr-2 -4
Apr-2 -6
Apr-2 -8
Apr-2 9
```

I need to display count by `range: <=4` , from `>4 to <8` and `>= 8` and then display group by day in column. like this:

```
Day      <=4     >4 & <8    >= 8
--------------------------------
Apr-1     3         1         1
Apr-2     3         0         1
```

I did some tests and research with `awk uniq`... but I got no results

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '
    {days[$1] = 1}
    $2 <= 4 {a[$1]++} 
    4 < $2 && $2 < 8 {b[$1]++} 
    $2 >= 8 {c[$1]++} 
    END {
        OFS="\t"; 
        print "Day","<=4", "4<x<8", ">=8"; 
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"; 
        for (day in days) 
            print day, a[day]+0, b[day]+0, c[day]+0
    }
' <<END | column -t 
Apr-1 -4
Apr-1 -2
Apr-1 -5
Apr-1 5
Apr-1 95
Apr-2 -4
Apr-2 -6
Apr-2 -8
Apr-2 9
END
```

```
Day    <=4  4<x<8  >=8
Apr-1  3    1      1
Apr-2  3    0      1
```

The reason for adding zero to the values when printing is that empty values (such as Apr-2 4<x<8) will show up as empty strings. When forced into a numeric context by adding zero, they show up as 0.